# Fisheye Crucible API web service call only shows recently viewed items

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, querying, atlassian-fisheye

I am trying to use the Fisheye Crucible API to get information regarding Crucible reviews and Jiras associated with them.

I can successfully see recently viewed reviews along with their corresponding Jira ID by calling the following API :

http://host:port/context/rest-service-fecru/recently-visited-v1/reviews/detailed

However, I don't see anything equivalent to see all the reviews and associated JIRAs. The below REST API service call does not work:

http://host:port/context/rest-service-fecru/recently-visited-v1/reviews/detailed

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to see all the reviews:

```
select revisions where reviewed
```

and put it in the query format as follows to search across repos:

```
http://host:port/context/rest-service-fe/search-v1/crossRepositoryQuery?query=select revisions from reviewed
```

or repo specific:

```
http://host:port/context/rest-service-fe/search-v1/query/{repository}?query=select revisions from reviewed
```

**References**

- [rest-service-fe: query repository](https://docs.atlassian.com/fisheye-crucible/latest/wadl/fisheye.html#rest-service-fe:search-v1:query:repository)
- [rest-service-fe: crossRepositoryQuery](https://docs.atlassian.com/fisheye-crucible/latest/wadl/fisheye.html#rest-service-fe:search-v1:crossRepositoryQuery)
- [EyeQL Reference Guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/eyeql-reference-guide-298976796.html)
- [JIRA REST API Reference](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/)
- [REST API Guide - Atlassian Developers](https://developer.atlassian.com/fecrudev/remote-api-reference/rest-api-guide)
- [FishEye and Crucible Knowledge Base Home - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb)